# image galleries - auto generated?

Tags: gallery

Craft looks VERY promising to me! Still try to figure out if it could be perfect for our new project, though.

Can those requirements be fulfilled by craft?

- Is there an image gallery module where i can define captions? means small (copyright)text under the thumbnails and also under the enlarged images (say, in a modal)?
- Can I define a folder full of images and tell Craft to use this as the source for my gallery, so it automatically generates the gallery for me? An image description (or alt text etc.) should automatically be used and displayed as captions.

I'll open another question for my questions concerning my other topics...

Thanks a lot for your help and greetings!

Comment: Not really worth a full answer so just as a comment: yes it's all possible. Nearly everything is possible in Craft since it's more like a blank canvas and not doesn't have any expectations about your content structure. So you won't see a module like "gallery" somewhere but create a section "galleries" with a field caption and work with that